# iPhoneOS, using applicationWillResignActive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiapplication

I want to use this function applicationWillResignActive perform some tasks.
before the application shuts down due to incoming call, message or user close it manually.

Can i send an email message/in app sms using this function ? Will those tasks would be performed or the application would immediately quit due to the above mentioned interrupts.
Thank you all.

Taimur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before sending email or sms on iOS you have to display standard UI to user (either MFMailComposeViewController or MFMessageComposeViewController), but you can't present any new UI when application is going to resign active state, so the answer is no - those tasks cannot be performed

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, i want to know can we send an email at a certain during while the app is running without notifying user.